# Why isn't my program printing out the correct message?

Tags: c, string, printing

I'm trying to write a program to see if string 1 is a part of string 2. At the command prompt, I enter string 1, and then string 2. But the problem is, no matter what I type, my program keeps printing out the answer that "No, string 1 is not a part of string 2". I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong, is there something wrong with my for loop? Help is appreciated!

```
int string_part_of_other(void)
{
   char str1[20];
   char str2[20];
   int answer = 1;

   printf("Enter string 1:\n");
   scanf("%s", str1);

   printf("Enter string 2:\n");
   scanf("%s", str2);

   for (int i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; str2[j] != '\0'; j++)
      {
         if (str1[i] != str2[j])
         {
            answer = 0;
         }
      }
   }

   return answer;
}

int main()
{
   int result;
   result = string_part_of_other();

   if (result == 1)
   {
      printf("Yes, string 1 is part of string 2.\n");
   }

   if (result == 0)
   {
      printf("No, string 1 is not part of string 2.\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fundamentally, because the algorithm is wrong.  You set `answer` to 0 on the first mismatch, but never reset it to 1.  You should probably invert the logic.  If you find every character in string 2 in a stretch of string 1, return 1 from the function (in the body of the inner loop).  Otherwise, return 0 at the end of the function.

Comment: this logic is incorrect.. your "answer" variable is always 0 if ever there is a different character in both strings.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffer - I don't believe your comment is correct. Consider the array indices that are being compared, there is something more fundamentally broken.

Comment: You need to modify your logic.You are comparing every single character of string 1 with complete str2 string, which is wrong.

Comment: @patros: I don't see what you're suggesting.  I see code comparing `str1[i]` with `str2[j]`, which at least compares two characters from two different strings, with index `i` scanning over `str1` and index `j` scanning over `str2`.  That much seems about right.  There are problems with the chosen algorithm, but ...

Comment: Suggestion(Not an answer): Put `return 0;` in `if()` statement, it will improve performance.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler As written it compares each character from a string with every character from another string. As in, only return true if all characters in string 1 matches every character in string 2. If string 1 and 2 are not composed entirely of the same  character this will always return false even if you reverse the order.

Comment: @patros: that's basically what I said when I noted that the code sets `answer` to 0 on the first mismatch and never resets it to 1.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Maybe it's just a bit vague. My main concern is that i is static in the inner loop while j is being incremented.  Comparing string1[i+j] to string2[j] would work, if as you suggest 1 is returned when a match is found (returning checking for the end of string1).

Comment: I just want to thank EVERYONE for all the tips/help! :) It really means a lot to me when people take the time to help clear up a question. :)

Comment: @Karen You can accept only one answer at a time - if you tick another one, the others will be unaccepted.

Comment: Ohh, I see so that's why...thanks. :) I'll keep looking at all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your loop. You're comparing an entire string against one character.

```
for (int i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++){
   for (int j = 0; str2[j] != '\0'; j++){ // here
      if (str1[i] != str2[j]) answer = 0; 
   }
}
```

`strpbrk` or `strstr` is a function that does this automatically, if that's what you would prefer.

You could also try this:

```
for (int i = 0; str1[i]; i++){
    int j = 0;
    for (; str2[j] && str1[i + j]; j++){
        if (str2[j] != str1[i + j]) break;
    }
    if (!str2[j]) return 1; /*
    * This means the loop broke because it reached the end of the
    * string, not because of a mismatch. Therefore, str2 is within str1
    */
}

return 0;
```

Also, I think it is your intention to say `string 2 is part of string 1`, and not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the comments about functions that already do this, but I need to practice programming! :) And I see what you're saying, so if I wanted to compare the two strings, I would have to use strcmp() right??

Comment: @Karen For comparing strings, yes. But for finding substrings, no.

Comment: @Karen: using `strcmp()` works to compare strings for sorting in order, but doesn't handle comparing substrings (which you'd need to do).  You want to find out if `str2` exists as a string in `str1`.  Apart from heading off wasted effort if `str2` is longer than `str1` (it will never be found), you do then dive into a double loop, unless you get fancy with Boyer-Moore or Knuth-Morris-Pratt or some other more sophisticated string search algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you've written answers the following:

"For each character in string1, does it match every character in string2?"

If you step through the code in your head you should be able to figure out what's going wrong, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Few remarks:

- don't use `scanf()`. It doesn't do what you think it does, and it even goes unprotected without the ability to specify field width, so you should expect buffer overruns.
- so use `fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)` instead (and beware of trailing newlines).
- Don't reinvent the wheel: there's a function called `strstr()` in the C standard library which does exactly what you want, and it works correctly unlike your current ugly-hack-with-unreadable-nested-for-loops.

All in all:

```
int part_of()
{
    char buf1[LINE_MAX], buf2[LINE_MAX], *p;
    fgets(buf1, sizeof(buf1), stdin);
    fgets(buf2, sizeof(buf2), stdin);

    p = strchr(buf1, '\n');
    if (p) *p = 0;
    p = strchr(buf2, '\n');
    if (p) *p = 0;

    return strstr(buf1, buf2) != NULL;
}
```

Also, don't write `if (func() == 1) {}` then `if (func() == 0) {}` immediately afterwards - redundancy is bad. `if (func()) {} else {}` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if your last char in `str1` and last char in `str2` do not match each other, the `answer` will be `0`. Even if `str2` is a part of `str1`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (str1[i] != str2[j]) {
            answer = 0;
}
```

If the 1st literal in your string1 does not match with string2 answer is set to 0, after that even if you find the substring you are not changing answer to 1 so you are not getting the proper result.

Also you are just incrementing str2 index and not incrementing str1 index with it, so you will never find the string, so change the logic.

Answer (score 0):

you are just comparing all characters of str1 with that of str2 and even if one mismatch is there you set answer to zero .. wrong logic based on asked question
I am assuming you want to check str1 to be a part of str2, the outer loop should be of the parent or containing string in this case str2 ...

```
    int answer=0;
    for(int i=0;str2[i]!='\0';i++) //traversing bigger string
    {
    if(str2[i]==str1[0])
    //if character of bigger string matches first  character small string
    {
    for(int j=0;str1[j]!='\0';j++)
    { 
    if(((i+j)<strlen(str2))&&(str1[j]!=str2[i+j])){
    break;}
    }//j
    if(str1[j-1]=='\0')
    {answer=1;
     break;}
    }//i
```

Answer (score -1):

I rewrite some of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int string_part_of_other(void)
{
   char str1[20];
   char str2[20];
   int answer = 0;
   int i, j, k;

   printf("Enter string 1:\n");
   scanf("%s", str1);

   printf("Enter string 2:\n");
   scanf("%s", str2);

   i = j = k =0;

   while(str2[j] !='\0')
   {
       k = j;
       for(i = 0; str1[i] != '\0' && str2[k] != '\0'; i++, k++)
       {
           if(str1[i] != str2[k])
           {
               break;
           }
       }

       if(str1[i] == '\0')
       {
           answer = 1;
       }
       j++;

   }

   return answer;
}

int main()
{
   int result;
   result = string_part_of_other();

   if (result == 1)
   {
      printf("Yes, string 1 is part of string 2.\n");
   }

   if (result == 0)
   {
      printf("No, string 1 is not part of string 2.\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```